# Angular 10 Web Worker: Cannot find base TypeScript configuration file 'tsconfig.base.json'

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

Whenever I try to do:

`ng g web-worker canvas`

I keep getting

`Cannot find base TypeScript configuration file 'tsconfig.base.json'.`

I look through my files and I indeed don't have a tsconfig.base.json

I have tried to find other chains that explain how to do it but I have not had any luck. I think it is because most of the posts are from people upgrading from another angular version to the current one But this is a brand new project...

Anyone Knows how to generate it?

Here is all of my info:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.1.0
Node: 12.18.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.1.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                               Version
---------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect             0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular         0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr      0.1001.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer       0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack         0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core                  10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics            10.0.8
@angular/cdk                          10.2.7
@angular/localize                     10.0.8
@angular/platform-webworker           8.0.0
@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic   8.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                      10.0.4
@schematics/angular                   10.0.8
@schematics/update                    0.1001.0
ng-packagr                            10.1.0
rxjs                                  6.6.3
typescript                            4.0.3
webpack                               4.46.0
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading I realized that my @schematics/angular was not installed. after installing that it started working.